# Is there a way to apply the animation of the rigid body to mesh?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cell-fracture

I wanted to apply the result of the animation to my mesh, so that I get a fractured flower pot. Is there a way to do that?
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please tell what exactly you mean by "apply the result of the animation to my mesh", do you mean you want to bake to keyframes?

Comment: I want to get a mesh that looks like the one on the picture. Which is the final result of the rigid body simulation. Can I simply 'apply' the simulation to get that fractured mesh without any animation and rigid body sim on it?

Comment: You can select the objects then header menu > Object > Rigid Body > Apply Transformation, then get rid of the rigid body simulation in the Physics panel. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you. That helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the objects then header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Apply Transformation*, then get rid of the rigid body simulation in the *Physics* panel.